# Concluding that the Lebesgue measure of an open ball $B_r(0)$ is $\pi$r^2

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I recently computed the three-dimensional Lebesgue measure of the set $E := \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 : x,y,z \geq 0, x+y+z \leq 1\}$

With  $\lambda^3(E) = ab\pi r^2.$

I now want to conclude from this result, that the Lebesgue measure $\lambda^3(B_r(0)$ is $\pi r^2$ where $B_r(0) = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^3 x^2+ y^2< r \}$.

I know that this is true, because $B_r(0)$ is just a circle in the x-y plane, but how can I show that $\lambda^3(E) = ab\pi r^2 \Rightarrow \lambda^3(B_r(0)) = \pi r^2$ without having to compute $\lambda^3(B_r(0))$?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you mean $B_r(0) = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 \; : \; x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < r^2\}$.  And its measure is $(4/3) \pi r^3$.

Comment: Also, where are you getting that $ab\pi r^2$?  There is no $a$, $b$ or $r$ in the definition of $E$.